# Why do I have an error 500 and null data from ajax request in my Api controller?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

partial html code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<h1>Registration</h1>
<form id="loginform">
    <input type="number" name="Id" value="0" id="ID"/><br />
    <p>Имя</p>
    <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" /><br />
    <p>Ник</p>
    <input type="text" name="NickName" id="NickName" /><br />
    <p>Возраст</p>
    <input type="number" name="Age" id="Age" /><br />
    <p>Почта</p>
    <input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" /><br />
    <p>Пароль</p>
    <input type="text" name="Password" id="Password" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="отправить" id="Submit" />
</form>

<script>
    function submitForm(form, url) {
// let formData = $(form).serialize();
var person = new Object();
person.Id = $("#ID").val();
person.Name = $("#Name").val();
person.Age = $("#Age").val();
person.NickName = $("#NickName").val();
person.Email = $("#Email").val();
person.Password = $("#Password").val();
        let response = "";
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data: {user:person},
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
})
        return response;
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Submit").on("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            let data = submitForm($("#loginform"), "/api/Test");
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Api controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    Context db;
    public TestController(Context context)
    {
        db = context;
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Registration([FromForm]User user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Users.Add(user);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return Ok(user);
        }
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
}
```

Simple model of User:

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string NickName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
```

I have tried $(form).serializeArray() in function submitForm but it throw error 500 in browser's console. I have tried JSON.stringify and serializeArray. 
In which cases should I not use [FromForm] and [FromBody]? I have seen many examples without this attributes

Comment: Actually, Error 500 occurs when there is an Internal Server Error. I'll suggest you to restart the server and try again.

Comment: @kartiktyagi it did not help

Comment: I am honestly not trying to condescend with this suggestion, so if I am being too simplistic please forgive me. When I get an Error 500, I place a breakpoint at or near the beginning of the method being called (in this case Registration([FromForm] User user)), then examine the incoming data for validity, and step through to see where the error occurs.